# value entered in simple text box not able to persist after closing app-iphone

Tags: iphone

i have a class named A
In class A,there is a simple "text box",a button and a label user enter his name click on "ok" button.
By clicking on "ok" button  name is displayed in label.

**Problem:
How to persist data entered in text box so that even if application get closed the data should be remained in that label.**
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use NSUserDefaults.

Here is another topic that will help you: [Stackoverflow userDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962591/best-practices-for-handling-user-preferences-in-an-iphone-mvc-app)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the database connection for your application.use SQLITE.. [see this for sqlite tutorial](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/tutorial-discussion/4086-my-iphone-sqlite-tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply! for single text value database no way?any other way?

Answer (score 0):

you can save the value in plist or in the database or in NSUSERDEFAULTS..

So whenever you comes on the view you can restore value.

Comment: a more descriptive answer will be very helpful.with reference to above question!

Answer (score 0):

Store by using the fololwing code
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: forKey:@""];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

Retrieve by using the following code
NSString *storedStr=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@""];