# Plist won't write to file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, filesystems, plist

When i try this code:

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"~/Library/Application Support/Staying Afloat/stats/static-stats.plist"] == NO) {
    NSMutableDictionary* tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"0"],@"completedGames",
                                     [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"0"],@"floatsCollected",
                                     [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"0"],@"sec",
                                     [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"0"],@"subScore",
                                     [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"0"],@"highScore",
                                     [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"0"],@"longestSec", nil];

    [tempDict writeToFile:@"~/Library/Application Support/Staying Afloat/stats/static-stats.plist" atomically:YES];

    NSLog(@"written file");

}
```

and this outputs with

```
2012-04-14 19:15:10.009 Staying Afloat[3227:9c07] written file
```

so the loop has run, but the file isn't written?
can anyone point my in the right dirrection for saving plists to non-localized places?

**EDIT:** this is for mac

Comment: Do the diretories "Staying Afloat/stats/" exists?

Comment: You could try `writeToFile:options:error:` to get the error message...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to expand your path using `-(NSString *)stringByExpandingTildeInPath` when you write and check if the file exist.

**Edit:** Read the method `writeToFile:automatically` in the NSDictionary documentation.  It says

> If path contains a tilde (~) character, you must expand it with stringByExpandingTildeInPath before invoking this method.

So just do something like

```
[tempDict writeToFile:[[NSString stringWithString:@"~/Library/Application Support/Staying Afloat/stats/static-stats.plist"] stringByExpandingTildeInPath] atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

first you can't just write :

```
[tempDict writeToFile:@"~/Library/Application Support/Staying Afloat/stats/static-stats.plist" atomically:YES];

NSLog(@"written file");
```

because you don't check if the file was really written with success or not.

you should write :

```
if([tempDict writeToFile:@"~/Library/Application Support/Staying Afloat/stats/static-stats.plist" atomically:YES]) {
    NSLog(@"written file");
} else {
    NSLog(@"file not written");
}
```

WriteToFile method returns a Boolean.

Comment: it returns "file not written"

Answer (score 0):

I always use NSUserDefaults which takes care of everything for you with things like user prefs or storing app states between running. Off the top of my head I'd suggest you haven't got the right privileges to write a plist and what happens if you accidentally destroy a vital key and value for the os? Have a look at

[Best practices for handling user preferences in an iPhone MVC app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962591/best-practices-for-handling-user-preferences-in-an-iphone-mvc-app)

Comment: Read the tags, he's doing this for a mac, not iOS.

Comment: Oops. Maybe I shouldn't use a small screen to answer questions! My mistake.

Comment: However, I would say that in my Mac OSX app I use NSUserDefaults which is what the link talks about just for iPhone in this instance but there is a MacOSX version: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `-writeToFile:atomically:` returns `YES`?

Comment: It does for iOS, right click on 'writeToFile' and read the short description. Returns YES if the file is written successfully, otherwise NO.

Comment: I'm not saying that it can't or doesn't return YES. Just that you should check like NSLog(@"%d", [... writeToFile:atomically:]);